# How to repair USB flash drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have some kind of 8 Gb `Feiya Technology Corp. Flash Drive`, which is stopped working - it is seen by the system, but I can not write any info there. I tried to use some of Transcend recovery tool and in result now it is seen as 16 Gb Transcend drive. My primary system is OSX, but I can use Windows also to test/repair it.

The first question is how to restore it is correct size? Looks like I can use TestDisk to change drive geometry, but what should be correct number of cylinders, heads, sectors and sector size? Now it shows

```
Disk /dev/rdisk1 - 15 GB / 14 GiB - 31108608 sectors, sector size=512
```

Answer (score -1):

At first I would try to figure out the real capacity, because market is full of counterfeit USB flash drives from China, e.g. using:

[H2testw 1.4 – Gold Standard In Detecting USB Counterfeit Drives (win/mac/linux)](https://sosfakeflash.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/h2testw-14-gold-standard-in-detecting-usb-counterfeit-drives/)

And then, if applicable, I would try to [repair it (by fixing VID+PID)](https://fixfakeflash.wordpress.com/2008/12/11/about-vid-pid-repairing-counterfeit-flash-drives-steps-to-succeed/).